# how to set imageView position in child layout

Tags: android

I have nested layouts. inside relative layout i want to set images for dragging but problem is images cross their boundaries and can be dragged to other layout. I want to restrict images in their region so that they cannot be dragged outside their boundary. I have calculated width and height of particular layout but i could not set the images on particular layout.Any solution please?
xml Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/R1Layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/wood_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/R2Layout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/wood_bg" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playerimage1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playerimage2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:src="@drawable/player1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playerimage2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/playerimage4"
                android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playerimage1"
                android:src="@drawable/player2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playerimage3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playerimage2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playerimage2"
                android:layout_weight="0.16"
                android:src="@drawable/player3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playerimage4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playerimage3"
                android:src="@drawable/player4" />

            </RelativeLayout>

    < ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

            android:src="@drawable/chat" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/R3Layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/imageButton1"
            android:background="@drawable/ludo" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_x="0dp"
                android:layout_y="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/green" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_x="0dp"
                android:layout_y="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/green2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_x="0dp"
                android:layout_y="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/green3" />

        </RelativeLayout>  
    </RelativeLayout>
```

here is the .java file code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // MediaPlayer music =
        // MediaPlayer.create(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this, R.raw.playback);+

        rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.R3Layout);
    //  r2Layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.R2Layout2);
    //  r1Layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.R1Layout);
        //int value= this.rLayout();
        //rLayout.layout(10, 10, 10, 10);
    //  {
    //  RelativeLayout rLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        x1 = (int) ((76 * width) / 100);
        y1 = (int) ((11 * height) / 100);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(480,423);
        //params.leftMargin = x1;
        //params.topMargin = y1;
        img1.setLayoutParams(params);
        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        x2 = (int) ((69 * width) / 100);
        y2 = (int) ((11 * height) / 100);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params2.leftMargin = x2;
        params2.topMargin = y2;
        img2.setLayoutParams(params2);
        img1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                status = 1;

                // Log.i("ImageStatus", "" + status);
                // img.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                int[] values = new int[2];
                img1.getLocationOnScreen(values);
                // img.getLocationInWindow(values);
                int x = values[0];
                int y = values[1];

                /*
                 * if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ //
                 * if(v.getId()==R.id.imageView){} int eventX=(int)event.getX();
                 * int eventY=(int)event.getY(); int[] values = new int[2];
                 * values[0]= eventX; values[1]= eventY; Log.i("x is @@@@@@@@",
                 * +values[0]+ "y is @@@@@@@:" +values[1]);
                 * //Toast.makeText(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this,
                 * " x is : "+x+ // "y :"+y , 5000).show(); } if
                 * (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){ int
                 * eventX=(int)event.getX(); int eventY=(int)event.getY(); int[]
                 * values = new int[2]; values[0]= eventX; values[1]= eventY;
                 * Toast.makeText(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this, " x is : "+x+
                 * "y :"+y , 5000).show();
                 */

                // }

                // mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shake);
                // mp.start();

                return false;
            }
        });
        img2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                status = 2;
                // lp2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) img2.getLayoutParams();
                // Log.i("ImageStatus", "" + status);
                // img.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                int[] values = new int[2];
                img2.getLocationOnScreen(values);
                // img.getLocationInWindow(values);
                int x2 = values[0];
                int y2 = values[1];
                // Toast.makeText(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this,
                // " x2 is : "+x2+ "y2 :"+y2 , 500).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        rLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            // green

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (status == 1) // any event from down and move
                {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,423);
                    params.topMargin = (int) event.getY() - img1.getHeight() / 2;
                    params.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - img1.getWidth() / 2;
                    // LayoutParams lp = new
                    // LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)event.getX()-img.getWidth()/2,(int)event.getY()-img.getHeight()/2);
                    img1.setLayoutParams(params);
                    // img.setPadding(20, 40, 20, 40);
                    // img.setBaseline(baseline)

                }
                if (status == 2) // any event from down and move
                {

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.topMargin = (int) event.getY() - img2.getHeight()
                            / 2;
                    params.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - img2.getWidth()
                            / 2;
                    img2.setLayoutParams(params);

                }
```

Comment: You should probably post some code / your layout first. People like to work ON something rather than posting random solutions that can be easily missunderstood or not used as intended.

Comment: I have added code...have a look please.
i want to set images by calculating layouts height for real time communication

Answer (score 0):

Using marings isn't probably the most preferable idea for this. Instead, have a look at this class https://github.com/rfreedman/android-constrained-drag-and-drop-view/blob/master/src/main/java/net/greybeardedgeek/ConstrainedDragAndDropView.java

especially

```
protected void updateDragPosition(MotionEvent motionEvent) {}
```

method should give you an idea how to do it. Get your target View, get its boundaries (remember that the view have to be drawn first, but if you are using listeners that shouldn't be that much of a hassle) and you are good to go.

Comment: dragged images are going outside the layout,,,,on top and bottom,,how can i tell images to keep in particular layout??